# How to fix DataGridView Error: Is it possible that my null field result in MySQL query is the cause?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, runtime-error

I was trying to show my query result using a datagridview when i bumped into these errors...

The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.IMage.FromStream(Stream stream, BooleanuseEmbeddedColorManagement,     Boolean validateImageData)
at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,     CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObjectInternal(Objectvalue, Type targetTyep,     TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString,     IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue)
at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObject(Object value, Type targetType,     TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString,     IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)
at System.Window.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetFormattedValue(Object value, Int32 rowIndex,     DataGridViewCellStyle& cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,     TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

Well, I do get something like 8 dialogs like this when I use the datagridview, however, when I run a line-by-line checking using a breakpoint, I don't get prompted for a single error! I think it's this datagridview. I already tried to delete the datagridview and just put a new one but the same problem exists.

for your reference, here is the code I use in putting data into my datagridview:

```
  Public Sub fillDGVBulk()
    Try

        Dim bulkCmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from " _
                                    + "( " _
                                    + "  select controlno, bulk.catid, bulk.bcode, " _
                                    + "  ( " _
                                    + "    bulk.itemqty " _
                                    + "  ) as stock, " _
                                    + "  case when resv.qty is null then " _
                                    + "  '0' else resv.qty end as booked, " _
                                    + "  case when " _
                                    + "  ( " _
                                    + "    bulk.itemqty-sumqty " _
                                    + "  ) is null then " _
                                    + "  bulk.itemqty else (bulk.itemqty-sumqty) end as available, bulk.itemname, bulk.deptcode, bulk.loccode, resv.resdate, resv.timestart, resv.timeend " _
                                    + "  from tbl_items_bulk bulk " _
                                    + "  left join " _
                                    + "  ( " _
                                    + "    select rs.controlno, rs.bcode, rs.qty, sum(rs.qty) as sumqty, rs.resdate, rs.timestart, rs.timeend " _
                                    + "    from tbl_reservations rs " _
                                    + "    where retdate is null " _
                                    + "    and restype='1' " _
                                    + "    and resdate = @date " _
                                    + "    and not " _
                                    + "    ( " _
                                    + "      (timestart between @tStart and @tEnd) or " _
                                    + "      (timeend between @tStart and @tEnd) or " _
                                    + "      (timestart <= @tStart and timeend >= @tEnd) " _
                                    + "    ) " _
                                    + "    or rs.bcode is null " _
                                    + "    and (claimdate is null and retdate is null) " _
                                    + "    group by bcode " _
                                    + "  ) resv " _
                                    + "  on bulk.bcode=resv.bcode " _
                                    + "  where ((bulk.itemqty-sumqty) >= 1) or (bulk.itemqty-sumqty) is null " _
                                    + "  order by resdate, timestart " _
                                    + ") rvs " _
                                    + "where rvs.catid=@catid " _
                                    + "order by controlno", conn)

        With bulkCmd
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", cbo_catbulk.SelectedValue.ToString)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dtp_datebulk.Value.ToString)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tStart", cbo_startbulk.SelectedValue.ToString)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tEnd", cbo_endbulk.SelectedValue.ToString)
        End With

        Dim DAdapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter()

        DAdapter2.SelectCommand = bulkCmd

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
            conn.Open()
        Else
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim table2 As New DataTable
        DAdapter2.Fill(table2)

        DataGridView2.DataSource = table2

        conn.Close()

        'controlno, catid, bcode, stock, booked, available, resdate, timestart, timeend

        With DataGridView2
            .Columns(0).Visible = False
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Category ID"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Barcode"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Stock"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Booked"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Available"
            ' .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Item"
            .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Department"
            .Columns(8).HeaderText = "Storage Area"
            .Columns(9).Visible = False
            .Columns(10).Visible = False
            .Columns(11).Visible = False
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString + " Error No: " + Err.Number.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a wild guess here..

During runtime, while this code sets table2 as the dataSource of the DataGridView,

```
DataGridView2.DataSource = table2
```

these codes *immediately* runs...

```
With DataGridView2
            .Columns(0).Visible = False
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Category ID"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Barcode"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Stock"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Booked"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Available"
            ' .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Item"
            .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Department"
            .Columns(8).HeaderText = "Storage Area"
            .Columns(9).Visible = False
            .Columns(10).Visible = False
            .Columns(11).Visible = False
        End With
```

Which will rename/hides the columns.

Rather renaming the DataGridView2's column header texts,
which I think causes the runtime error, because it doesn't yet have the columns of the result set.

Why not use the AS keyword on the SELECT statement, so that you can rename the column names
of the result set of your query.

Try this on your initial select statement..

```
 Dim bulkCmd As New MySqlCommand("select catid AS `Category ID`, bcode AS `Barcode`, stock AS Stock, booked AS `Booked`, available AS `Available`, resdate AS `Item`, timestart AS `Department`, timeend AS `Storage Area` from " _
```